# UIView in Playground

Tags: swift, uiview, swift-playground

I have defined two views differently like-

**First method:**

```
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 667.0))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

I can see the rectangle.

**Second method:**

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

I see some log message like output.

Why both are giving different outputs?

Some tutorials in the web used first method and some the second one.

Here's the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, playground does not work as expected. Probably, it is because both views do not have superviews defined.

In real app it works fine.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 37.5, height: 66.7))
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


    view.addSubview(containerView)       

    let myView = UIView()
    myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 290, width: 200, height: 200)
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

I tried this code in playgorund:

```
let cv = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 667.0))
cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 60.0))
v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

cv.addSubview(v1)

let v2 = UIView()
v2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 30.0, height: 60.0)
v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()


cv.addSubview(v2)
```

and it works fine for both initialisers.

Comment: There is a preview for `cv`,`v1` but there is no preview for `v2`. I mean whenever `v2` type of defining is used, there is no preview. So, is it a bug? or anything else?

Comment: In my playground - I see them both. When I preview the cv, I see red and blue rectangle in it. Version 7.2 (7C68). It is highly probable it is a bug in playground.

Comment: I can only see `cv`,`v1` but I can't see `v2` when it is created. But I can see `v1`,`v2` inside `cv` when it is added.

Comment: it is obvious playground does not handle this well when there is not a superview. Further - I would check this with XCPlayground.

Comment: But, please, keep in mind - this is in playground only.